# How can I use the proof steps in the proof for the conservation of momentum to write equations for a 3-particle system?

Tags: classical-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws

I am being asked to restate the proof for the conservation of momentum and Newton's third law for a 3-particle system. The textbook's steps (for an N particle system) are as follows:

(1.25) (net force on particle $\alpha$) $=\vec{F}_{\alpha}=\sum_{\beta\neq\alpha}\vec{F}_{\alpha\beta}+\vec{F}_{\alpha}^{ext}$ (where $\vec{F}^{ext}$ represents an external force on $\alpha$)

The net force is also the rate of change of the momentum for particle $\alpha$

(1.26) $\dot{\vec{P_\alpha}}=\sum_{\beta\neq\alpha}\vec{F}_{\alpha\beta}+\vec{F}_{\alpha}^{ext}$

Consider the total momentum: $\vec{P}=\sum_{\alpha}\vec{P_\alpha}$

Differentiating the equations: $\dot{\vec{P}}=\sum_{\alpha}\dot{\vec{P_\alpha}}$

Substituting $\dot{\vec{P_\alpha}}$,

(1.27) $\dot{\vec{P}}=\sum_{\alpha}\sum_{\beta\neq{\alpha}}\vec{F}_{\alpha\beta}+\sum_{\alpha}\vec{F}_\alpha^{ext}$

The double sum contains N(N-1) terms in all. The elements $\vec{F}_\alpha\beta$ can each be paired with $\vec{F}_\beta\alpha$, such that

(1.28) $\sum{}_\alpha\sum_{\beta\neq\alpha}\vec{F}_{\alpha\beta}=\sum_\alpha\sum_{\beta>\alpha}{(\vec{F}_{\alpha\beta}+\vec{F}_{\beta\alpha})}$

The double sum on the right only includes values of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ with $\alpha<\beta$ and has half of many terms as that on the left. Each term is the sum of two forces, and by the third law, that sum is zero. Therefore,

(1.29) $\dot{\vec{P}}=\sum_{\alpha}\vec{F}_\alpha^{ext}\equiv\vec{F}^{ext}$

---

For the N=3 particle system, I have written what I believe are the equations (1.25) and (1.26)

(1.25) $\vec{F}_{net}=\vec{F}_{1,2}+\vec{F}_{1,3}+\vec{F}_{2,1}+\vec{F}_{2,3}+\vec{F}_{3,1}+\vec{F}_{3,2}+\vec{F}^{ext}_1+\vec{F}^{ext}_2+\vec{F}^{ext}_3$

(1.26) $\dot{\vec{P}}_1=\vec{F}_{1,2}+\vec{F}_{1,3}+\vec{F}^{ext}_1$ ; $\dot{\vec{P}}_2=\vec{F}_{2,1}+\vec{F}_{2,3}+\vec{F}^{ext}_2$ ; $\dot{\vec{P}}_2=\vec{F}_{3,1}+\vec{F}_{3,2}+\vec{F}^{ext}_3$

I am assuming my final answer will lead me to show that $$\dot{\vec{P}}=\vec{F}_1^{ext}+\vec{F}_3^{ext}+\vec{F}_3^{ext}$$

However, I am unsure of how to write the summations explicitly for each of particles in the steps leading to equation (1.29).